# Protractor not wait for https.request callback

Tags: protractor

I hit a Protractor issue, if I run this within "ts-node demo.js" it works well and can output the response code and response body.

But if I run this in Protractor it block, then can't get the expected output response code and body, seems like Protractor won't wait for the callback.

In this situation, how can I output the response code and boday?

it(`Check manifests V2 api`, async() => {

```
    const https = require('https')
    const options = {
      hostname: 'demo-quayecosystem-quay-quay.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/v2/quay/multiarchdemo/manifests/latest',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json'
      }
    }

    https.request(options, res => {
      browser.getTitle().then(()=>{
        console.log("starting.........");
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

        res.on('data', d => {
          process.stdout.write(d)
        })

      })
    })       

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The function above is an async and when you make your function async, then you should use the await keyword in front of the https.request or return it like this.

```
return https.request...
```

And another thing that could lead to problems are...

https.request is making a direct HTTP request, without using a browser
broser.getTitle() is using the browser to interact with the web page.

Be aware - browser uses the browser, and http.request uses direct HTTP from node.js - these are two different things. And it will lead to unpredictable things to mix them. So consider if you want to "test as a user" and then use the browser, or if you want to do the fastest possible test and "test as a website or javascript" and use HTTP.request.

Try reading the async/await page on the Protractor website. 
https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await

If you are puzzled about async/await consider seeing the video from Fun Fun Function on promises https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=568g8hxJJp4&t=251s.

Comment: If I update the code as the following, it won't execute the two console.log statements. 
 await browser.getTitle().then(()=>{

            https.request(options, res => {

                console.log("starting.........");
                console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
            
                res.on('data', d => {
                  process.stdout.write(d)
                })
    
            }); 

        })

Comment: Hi Luffy, Be aware - browser uses the browser, and http.request uses direct HTTP from node.js - these are two different things. And it will lead to unpredictable things to mix them. So consider if you want to "test as a user" and then use the browser, or if you want to do the fastest possible test and "test as a website or javascript" and use HTTP.request.

Hope this helps